# Extracting the seconds until midnight with joda time

Tags: java, jodatime

I have two timestamps. (Start and end) It could happen that one time stamp is from yesterday.
If this happens, I want to know the exact seconds until 12 pm (until the day switches to today) and then the rest until the present timestamp. 
It could also happens the start date is a few days ago, then I would like to have the seconds from one day to another until today.

I feel like this can be most efficiently done using joda time, but can't figure out how.
Thx

```
**Example**

Start: timestamp(yesterday 23.55)
End: timestamp(today 00.02)

Should Return:
 Date of yesterday: 300 seconds
 Date of today: 120 seconds.

Another example:
Start date: timestamp( day before yesterday 23.58)
End date: timestamp(00.02)

Should return:
 Date of day before yesterday: 120 seconds
 Yesterday: 86400 seconds
 Today: 120 seconds
```

Comment: I don't think I follow you... but I'll venture to say that you might want to use the method `roundFloorCopy` on the current date to truncate the hour, minute, second, millis and then subtract the other date using `getDifferenceAsLong`. Is this somehow in the right direction?

Comment: @Augusto see my edit

Comment: I think the methods I mentioned can do what you want, as long as you return a list with all the bits of dates you want (e.g. what happens if the start is 5 days ago?): do you want a "start", "middle" and Today? (I have no idea how to call those bits of elapsed seconds).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this? It correctly handles time zones where there is no midnight during DST switch-over.

```
private static void listSecondsPerDayBetween(DateTime from, DateTime to) {
    System.out.println(from.toString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") + " - " + to.toString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
    if (! from.isBefore(to))
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Values are inverted: " + from + ", " + to);
    LocalDate date = from.toLocalDate().plusDays(1);
    DateTime nextMidnight = date.toDateTimeAtStartOfDay();
    DateTime prev = from;
    while (nextMidnight.isBefore(to)) {
        Seconds seconds = Seconds.secondsBetween(prev, nextMidnight);
        System.out.println("  " + prev.toString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "  " + seconds.getSeconds() + " seconds");
        prev = nextMidnight;
        date = date.plusDays(1);
        nextMidnight = date.toDateTimeAtStartOfDay();
    }
    Seconds seconds = Seconds.secondsBetween(prev, to);
    System.out.println("  " + prev.toString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "  " + seconds.getSeconds() + " seconds");
}
```

**Test**

```
listSecondsPerDayBetween(DateTime.parse("2016-01-31T23:55:00"),
                         DateTime.parse("2016-02-01T00:02:00"));
System.out.println();
listSecondsPerDayBetween(DateTime.parse("2016-02-01T09:45:00"),
                         DateTime.parse("2016-02-01T11:13:00"));
System.out.println();
listSecondsPerDayBetween(DateTime.parse("2016-03-11T23:55:00"),
                         DateTime.parse("2016-03-15T00:02:00"));
```

**Output**

```
2016-01-31 23:55:00 - 2016-02-01 00:02:00
  2016-01-31  300 seconds
  2016-02-01  120 seconds

2016-02-01 09:45:00 - 2016-02-01 11:13:00
  2016-02-01  5280 seconds

2016-03-11 23:55:00 - 2016-03-15 00:02:00
  2016-03-11  300 seconds
  2016-03-12  86400 seconds
  2016-03-13  82800 seconds
  2016-03-14  86400 seconds
  2016-03-15  120 seconds
```

Notice how March 13 is shorter because of Daylight Savings Time.

Answer (score 1):

Note that you don't want "midnight", you want the ["start of day"](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#withTimeAtStartOfDay()) - it's a subtle difference, but in certain timezones, on certain days, there is no midnight.

Assuming that your timestamps are in `DateTime` instances with the appropriate timezone:

```
DateTime startOfDay = end.withTimeAtStartOfDay();
if (startOfDay.isAfter(start)) {
  // startOfDay is after start, meaning that start and end are on different days.
  Seconds secondsBeforeSod = Seconds.secondsBetween(start, startOfDay);
  Seconds secondsAfterSod = Seconds.secondsBetween(startOfDay, end);
}
```